# C# LINQ query with joins and multiple counts

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I need to translate this SQL-query to Linq-Entity query

```
SELECT Company.name, COUNT(DISTINCT User.id), COUNT(DISTINCT Office.id)
FROM Company
INNER JOIN Office ON Company.id = Office.companyId
INNER JOIN Employee ON Office.id = Employee.officeId
GROUP BY Company.name
```

So I want a result that gives me a name of the company, count of unique employees and count of offices in a single row.

I have these entities

```
public class Company
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Office> offices { get; set; }
}

public class Office
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int companyId { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int officeId { get; set; }
}
```

and ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Company company { get; set; }
    public int employeeCount { get; set; }
    public int officeCount { get; set; }
}
```

What I have been trying in my controller:

```
var viewModel =
    from c in _context.Companies
    join o in _context.Offices on c.id equals o.companyId
    join e in _context.Employees on o.id equals e.officeId
    select new MyViewModel { company = c, employeeCount = ??, officeCount = 
    ??}

return View(viewModel);
```

So I don't know how the count() and group by are working.

Comment: can you add sample input and output screenshot of query too.

Comment: You are not using the group operator anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

First, LINQ has no direct equivalent of the SQL `COUNT(DISTINCT expr)` construct.

Second and more important, in LINQ to Entities you don't need to follow the SQL rules. We don't use joins, but navigation properties, and basically write the query like if we are working with objects, and let EF translate it to SQL.

The LINQ to Entities query in question is natural and simple as that:

```
var query = _context.Companies
    .Select(c => new MyViewModel
    {
        company = c,
        officeCount = c.offices.Count(),
        employeeCount = c.offices.Sum(o => o.employees.Count()),
    });
```